# How should I restore the finish on a fiberglass column?

Tags: paint, exterior, column

The exterior columns on my house have discolored over time but the AZEK trim around the house has had no issues. The column seems to be fiberglass material. I need to get it painted since power washing didn't do much. I'm not sure if it should be sprayed or brushed. Do I need primer? Does it need to be sanded first? Looking for some advice on what would work best and what type of paint to use. Thank you!

[image: exterior column]

[image: front of house]

[image: column close up]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes to primer, but probably not sanding unless it's an odd glossy finish that primer would have trouble adhering to.  I really like acrylic paints for exterior use, and have had great use with them ever since I spent a college break summer painting houses.  Great coverage and really seems to last without being oil based and so hard to clean up.  You can brush, roll, or spray this stuff. Just for columns I'd probably just use a good quality brush.